# Why is resultcode always -1 here?

Tags: android

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode==IMAGE_REQUEST && requestCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null && data.getData()!=null)
        {
            uri=data.getData();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Picasso.get().load(uri).into(imageView);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

    }
```

Why is `resultCode` always -1 here? Is there anything wrong with this code or anywhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `requestCode==RESULT_OK` should be `resultCode==RESULT_OK`. You're checking wrong variable

Answer (score 0):

`requestCode==IMAGE_REQUEST && requestCode==RESULT_OK`

if requestCode == IMAGE_REQUEST so request code is never == RESULT_OK.

requestCode can't keep both value at the time except IMAGE_REQUEST == RESULT_OK.

Comment: I guess `requestCode==RESULT_OK ` should be `resultCode==RESULT_OK `

Comment: sorry. may be problem is somewhere else.